# Block physical keyboard input in EditText

Tags: android, input, keyboard, android-edittext, hardware

I have a EditText that should not allow the user to input anything through the keyboard (soft or hard). This EditText should only allow the user to input something through keys(buttons) displayed in the screen by the app.
I have disabled the soft keyboard, but I can't find a way to disable the hardware keyboard input. This input via hardware keyboard can be done using a emulator that is configured to allow input through the hardware keyboard.
So, my question is, How can I block the input via physical keyboard in a EditText?
Thank you!

Comment: TextView? Don't you mean EditText?

Comment: Why have an `EditText` in the first place, if the user cannot use it?

Comment: Sorry for the TextView, don't know what I had in mind when first wrote that, fixed.
@CommonsWare the user can use it, the difference is how the input is made. It is not made by the soft keyboard, it is made by some keys that the app display on the screen.

Comment: That does not answer my question. Why use an `EditText`? Why not just use a `TextView`? After all, if you use an `EditText`, and the user tries to use it and fails, what is going to stop the user from thinking that your app is broken?

Comment: I'm using a EditText because the field should behave and look like one EditText, the only difference is on the input method. Otherwise I could use a TextView. Hope that it's more clear now.
Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got it!
Code:

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Explanation:
Returning true will tell the listener that I've already handled the hardware keyboard input. Based on Android documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html)

> View.OnKeyListener: Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a **hardware** key event is dispatched to this view. The callback will be invoked before the key event is given to the view. This is only useful for **hardware** keyboards; a software input method has no obligation to trigger this listener.
>
> onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
>   Called when a **hardware** key is dispatched to a view.

Comment: This works, but unfortunately intercepts even navigational key presses once the field takes focus. So if a user is using a hardware keyboard to navigate, they get stuck in the field.

Comment: Hi @damien5314 for my case worked fine because the user should not be able to use a hardware or soft keyboard to interact with this field specifically. You should evaluate if that is your case.

Comment: Not work for me. Numeric symbols from virtual keyboard ignored too with this solution. Need to return `!return event.getDevice().isVirtual()` - that's will ignore only hardware keyboard.

Comment: Hi Alexey, it fits in my case because I didn't watend that the user interact with the EditText with both soft and hardware keyboard, only by some buttons on the screen. 
According to the documentation [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html) 
"Key presses in software keyboards will **generally NOT** trigger this method, although some may elect to do so in some situations."
So maybe that's is because you had to use this __isVirtual()__ method.

Comment: The input is going through the onKeyListner but returning true is not removing the default behavior. Did anyone get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could try these according to what you want in your xml layout

```
android:longClickable="false"
android:clickable="false"    
android:cursorVisible="false"
android:editable="false"
```

Then make the edittext show what the user typed through the keyboard you made in the app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, it didn't worked. =/
I've also tried to avoid the initial focus on that edittext, but if I start to type anything on my keyboard the field starts to fill up.