# Overriding setOnKeyListener for all EditTexts in my Android app?

Tags: android, android-edittext, overriding

I am attempting to ignore the input from any connected physical/hardware keyboard while still allowing soft-keyboard input.

By using the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36039125/3961748) I am able to accomplish what I need, but I must find and add that override to every EditText I have placed in my project.

I was wondering if it is possible to override the setOnKeyListener method for all EditTexts in an activity or the entire app?

Comment: How about using `dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)` of an `Activity`? It will give an event when the key pressed.

Answer (score 2):

Create a global variable that would hold your listener

```
View.OnKeyListener keyListener = new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Then just set it to all your editText

```
editText1.setOnKeyListener(keyListener);
editText2.setOnKeyListener(keyListener);
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT:**

You could also use an injector. [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) for example

```
@BindViews({ R.id.first_name, R.id.middle_name, R.id.last_name })
List<EditText> nameViews;
```

By this you library you dont have to do `findViewById()` and the best thing is you justcan achieve your desired things by just 1 line

```
nameViews.setOnKeyListener(keyListener);
```

The above code will set keyListener to 3 EditText